# update database when click button using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, updatemodel

I am new using Ruby On Rails so this question may seem stupid. I've been searching a lot tutorial and sort of understand what I could do, but what the code looks like exactly? how i should implement this and where to put them still confuse me.

I have a database called note which has two attributes, :note whose type is text and a foreign key called user_name whose type is string. In the main.html.erb, I have my main page and also a note pad whose is a text area. here's part of main

```
    <div class="four columns" id="note">
      <textarea id="area" style="width:250px; height:300px;" placeholder="Your notes starts here"><%= @note %></textarea>
      <div id="clear" class="primary btn pretty"><a href="#">Clear</a></div>
      <div class="secondary btn pretty"><%= link_to 'Save', controller: 'main', action: 'update_note', :remote => true, :method => :put %></div>
    </div>
```

By the way, I'm using Gumby. so My button is called "Save". I want the user to input their note in the txtfiled and when they click the "save" button, it will update the note database in the row according to the user_name. 
So my question is, should I write a action on main_controller or notes_controller. How should I do it. Sample could would be much helpful since I tried different way and it is really frustrating. 
I tried putting the code in the main_controller like this:

```
    def update_note
@note = Note.find_by(user_name: session[:user_name])

respond_to do |format|
  if@note.update_attributes(params[:note])
    format.html { redirect_to @note, :notice => 'Note was successfully updated.' }
    format.js
  else
    format.html { render :action => "edit" }
    format.js
  end
end
end
```

as well as tried to put code in notes_controller. but I get "No route match"

I totally mess up. And it'd due tomorrow! thanks for any help. It's so nice to refers me some link of tutorial but the anything related to my code would be more helpful!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you put your models file please? I wonder how do you join note with users as y ou said your foreign key is a string but it is supposed to be the same type than the id it is referencing (usually integer).
No routes match mean your controller can not handle the requested url when you save the form. Can you also put your route file?

Answer (score 3):

You would have to use a form for this or you can also do it by using Jquery Ajax.
First add a gem '**jquery-rails**' to **Gemfile** and then do bundle install.

in *Gemfile*:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Next require both **jquery** and **jquery_ujs** into your */app/assets/javascripts/application.js* manifest like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ujs
```

in */views/layouts/application.html.erb*:

```
<%=javascript_include_tag "application.js"%>
#I guess it will be already there
```

in `/views/main/home.html.erb`

```
<%= form_tag({:controller=>'main',:action=>'update_note'},:method=>:post,:id=>"update_note",:name=>'note_form',:remote=>true) do %>

    <div class="four columns" id="note">
      <textarea id="area" name="note" style="width:250px; height:300px;" placeholder="Your notes starts here"><%= @note %></textarea>
      <div id="clear" class="primary btn pretty"><a href="#">Clear</a></div>
      <div class="secondary btn pretty"><%= submit_tag 'Save' %></div>
    </div>

<%end%>
<div id="updated">

</div>
```

in *main_controller.rb*

```
def update_note

@note = Note.find_by(user_name: session[:user_name])

  if @note.update_attributes(params[:note])
    @updated = "true"
    format.js
  else
    @updated = "false"
    format.js #this will load update_note.js.erb
  end

end
```

Create a file update_note.js.erb under ../views/main/

Now in *app/views/main/update_note.js.erb*:

```
<%if @updated == "true"%>
          $('#updated').html("Your post has been successfully updated").show();
<%elsif @updated == "false"%>
          $('#updated').html("Your post could not be updated").show();
 <%end%>
```

And at last add this in */config/routes.rb*:

```
    #in Rails 3
    #match "main/update_note" => "main#update_note" 

    #in Rails 4
    match 'main/update_note' => 'main#update_note', :via => [:post]
```

Open this home page where you have the update_note textbox, open up console in Chrome/ Firefox. Now check under **Net tab** in the console (in Firefox) or **Network tab** (in Chrome) and check for the request being made when you click on **Save** button. Let me know if you find any difficulty.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I have some question. What does the <div id = "updated" in the main.html.erb do? Also it seems like I can't just add 'match "main/update_note" => "main#update_note"'in the route. the server will day **You should not use the `match` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method.** @Sahil

Comment: Once you update your database with the user's note it would be nice to show some response message to user. Therefore in this case I have placed a **div** with id **updated** to show the response. You can have any element on your page to show any type of response just change the jquery on the update_note.js.erb page. And for routes it works in rails 3. Which version you are using. May be you can have this line in routes.rb: **put "main/update_note"**

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry I forgot to mention the version. it is 4.1.1. My server could work but when I write something in the note pad and click the save button , nothing happened. neither of those response nor the database updated on http://0.0.0.0:3000/notes @Sahil

Comment: I did check it. I feel like I am easily mess up with all these different folders and files. So is it because my main page that showed to user is the app/view/main/home.html, so I need to put the update action inside the main_controller instead of notes_controller?  should I also need to do something to notes_controller or notes_view?  please bear with me : ) @Sahil

Comment: Ok can you please give the list of your controllers, and views. Also the page with the update note feature where is this located, which page you are using for the layout? Then I will be able to help you out.

Comment: controllers: application_controller; bookmarks_controller; main_controller; settings_controller; users_controller; notes_controller; weathers_controller; sessions_controller  total 8.The root is the home.html.erb which is inside the views/main. The main_controller has two actions now, one is home and another is update_note which I learned it from you.In the views, we have a layout folder, and in which we have application.html.erb,we use it as layout. I use the generate scaffold to generate the notes so it's controller has the default route.I didn't change anything in the notes_controller@Sahil